# Unable to start VM using libvirt-terraform

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I am using the [terraform libvirt provider](https://github.com/dmacvicar/terraform-provider-libvirt) and I am failing to start a VM. I have a drive mounted at a folder within `/home/dude/vmPool/`, and I have tried setting acl from looking at this [issue](https://github.com/jedi4ever/veewee/issues/996#issuecomment-375931044) which looks similar. I have also tried editing `/etc/libvirt/qemu.conf` and setting `user=root, group=root` which doesn't seem to help. I have noticed that the VM image gets created as root while the cloudinit iso is created as my user, I believe internally genisoimage is used by the provider but I have no idea how that affects the domain not being created. It fails with the following error:

`error: Failed to start domain ubuntu-terraform
error: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2018-12-06T14:14:22.519784Z qemu-system-x86_64: -drive file=/home/dude/vmPool/kvm.kthw.test/ubuntu-qcow2,format=qcow2,if=none,id=drive-virtio-disk0: Could not open '/home/dude/vmPool/kvm.kthw.test/ubuntu-qcow2': Permission denied`

I am using Ubuntu 18.04:

```
uname -a
Linux kvm-host 4.15.0-42-generic #45-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 15 19:32:57 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

Comment: Take a look at this discussion please. The solution there maybe would help you: https://github.com/dmacvicar/terraform-provider-libvirt/issues/546 Particularly this comment: https://github.com/dmacvicar/terraform-provider-libvirt/issues/546#issuecomment-612983090

Answer (score 3):

It is a known issue in terraform libvirt. Please refer to :https://github.com/dmacvicar/terraform-provider-libvirt/commit/22f096d9

Answer (score 0):

this sounds like an apparmor path violation due to using an uncommon path.
Please verify checking `dmesg` when triggering the issue if you see a deny message.

Then as a resolution please follow this [document on using uncommon paths](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LibvirtApparmor#Using_uncommon_paths)

TL;DR:

- use a common path
- add a local apparmor override to allow your path

Comment: I ended up disabling and removing apparmor entirely as it seemed to have issues even with using the default pool (/var/lib/libvirt/images). From the log messages, it seemed the start capabilites were not included in libvirt profile

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, and after some investigation terraform doesn't use dot for resource identifiers. So AppArmor only grants this image

```
/etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.libvirt.virt-aa-helper
```

file names:

```
...
/**.img r,
/**.raw r,
/**.qcow{,2} r,
/**.qed r,
/**.vmdk r,
/**.[iI][sS][oO] r,
/**/disk{,.*} r,
...
```

My terraform uses -qcow as name for each resource, so adding this to the list solved my problem:

```
/**-qcow{,2} r,
```

Comment: Also using as name propery of volume '<file>.qcow' or any AppArmor valid image names for libvirt solves the permission problem.